# Spark DataFrame CROSS APPLY for columns deaggregation

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Spark DataFrame **df** is given with a schema:

```
id, agg_values
432, 11 3.14 45 4.322
984, 1  9.22 45 22.17
```

I need to produce "deaggdegated" columns:

```
id, item_id, value
432, 11, 3.14
432, 45, 4.322
984, 1,  98.22
984, 45, 222.1
```

Parsing function:

```
  private def parse_agg_scores(line: String): List[(String, String)] = {
    val items: Array[String] = line.split(' ')
    val ids = Iterator.from(0, 2).takeWhile(_ < items.size).map(items(_))
    val scores = Iterator.from(1, 2).takeWhile(_ < items.size).map(items(_))
    ids.zip(scores).toList
  }
```

I tried flatMap but it doesn't work:

```
val res = df.flatMap{ row =>
      val line = row.getString(1)

      parse_agg_scores(line)
}
```

Comment: Please don't just say "it doesn't work" without saying in what way it doesn't work. Compile-time error, run-time error, unexpected output (and if so, what did you get and what did you expect)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a compile time error related to not importing sqlContext.implicits._
This is the solution I come up with:

```
  def unpivote_scores(df: DataFrame, colName: String, sqlContext: SQLContext): DataFrame = {
    import sqlContext.implicits._

    df.flatMap { row =>
      val video_id = row.getInt(0)
      val features = row.getString(1)

      val items: Array[String] = features.split(' ')
      val ids_string = Iterator.from(0, 2).takeWhile(_ < items.size).map(items(_))
      val scores_string = Iterator.from(1, 2).takeWhile(_ < items.size).map(items(_))

      val ids = ids_string.map(_.toInt)
      val scores = scores_string.map(_.toDouble)

      ids.zip(scores).toList.map(t => (video_id, t._1, t._2))
    }.toDF("VideoId", "FeatureId", "Score")
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create a new column with the 4-element arrays split into 2-element arrays, and `explode` on that column - and then split these 2-element arrays into separate columns:

```
val result = dataFrame.withColumn("tuples", explode(array(
    array($"agg_values"(0), $"agg_values"(1)),
    array($"agg_values"(2), $"agg_values"(3))
  )))
  .select($"id", $"tuples"(0) as "item_id", $"tuples"(1) as "value")

result.show()
// +---+-------+-----+
// | id|item_id|value|
// +---+-------+-----+
// |432|   11.0| 3.14|
// |432|   45.0|4.322|
// |984|    1.0| 9.22|
// |984|   45.0|22.17|
// +---+-------+-----+
```

**EDIT** in case each record might have a different number of "pairs" in `agg_values`, we'll need a UDF to convert the array into am array of pairs before exploding:

```
// UDF to turn an array of Doubles into an Array of 2-item Arrays
val groupPairs = udf {
  arr: mutable.WrappedArray[Double] => arr.grouped(2).toArray
}

val result = dataFrame
  .withColumn("pair", explode(groupPairs($"agg_values")))
  .select($"id", $"pair"(0) as "item_id", $"pair"(1) as "value")
```

Comment: This is an interesting solution but the length of (item_id, value) pairs is unknown. So, I cannot use the indexes like $"agg_values"(1) and (2).

Comment: I see. So we _do_ know `agg_values` is comprised of such "pairs" (i.e. its length is an even number), but we don't know how many such pairs exist? And each record might contain a different number of pairs?

Comment: Updated my answer - hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you Tzach. It is almost what I need. There is one issue - it looks like your code assumes that the agg_values type is a list () but it is actually a string that should be parsed. I finally come up with a solution (see my own answer). My problem was in not importing sqlContext.implicits._